# Which part of PostgreSQL code is handling type definition?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL when I call `NUMERIC(10,2)` to define a variable type. Which part of the PostgreSQL C code is handling it?

I am interested in knowing where the precision and scale are handled.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of parts.

The lexer and parser transforms it into a type name and type modifier.

The system catalogs and syscache look up `numeric` to find the matching type oid.

The numeric.c code handles the actual type input/output and operators, and interprets the type modifier.

The index access methods and index operator classes handle selection of operators for comparisons etc.